# How to make 'grep' use text and regex at same time?

Tags: bash, grep

I have a bash script where I'm using `grep` to find text in a file. The search-text is stored in a variable.

```
found=$(grep "^$line$" "$file")
```

I need grep to use regex while not interpret the variable `$line` as regex. If for example `$line` contains a character which is a regex operator, like `[`, an error is triggered:

`grep: Unmatched [`

Is it somehow possible to make `grep` not interpret the content of `$line` as regex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `-F` flag of `grep` to make it interpret the patterns as fixed strings instead of regular expressions.

In addition,
if you want the patterns to match entire lines (as implied by your `^$line$` pattern),
you can combine with the `-x` flag.

So the command in your post can be written as:

```
found=$(grep -Fx "$line" "$file")
```

Answer (score 0):

Way to tell `grep` that the characters provided are ordinary characters is to escape them properly, for example:

```
$ cat file
this
[that
not[
$ line=\\[          # escaped to mark [ as an ordinary character
$ grep "$line" file
that[
[not
$ line=[is]         # [ is part of a proper regex 
$ grep "$line" file
this
```

So the key is to escape the regex chars:

```
$ line=[
$ echo "${line/[/\\[}"
\[
$ grep "^${line/[/\\[}" file
[that
```

Or you could use awk:

```
$ line=[that
$ awk -v s="$line" '$0==s' file
[that
```

Comment: It is customary to comment when downvoting.

Comment: While I have not downvoted your answer, however in my case it does not help, since `line` is a variable inside the script, and I don't really have control about it's content. So covering every possible case would be an overkill...

Comment: Well, it is programming. Nobody said it was easy. @janos showed another way.